# Difficulty working with $\forall$ quantifiers in particular proofs.

Tags: functions, proof-writing, first-order-logic

I've been trying for a while now to prove that $(g \circ f) = ((g\circ f)^{-1})^{-1}$ as a corollary to one of the exercises in Tao's *Analysis I* book. I am trying to restrict myself to the following strategy because it **highlights an issue that I have seen come up several time in my proofs**.

The goal of this proof is to conclude with the statement that $\forall x \in X, (g \circ f (x)) = (((g\circ f)^{-1})^{-1}(x))$. This is the definition of function equality.

Also, just for clarity: $f: X \to Y$ and $g:Y \to Z$

Here is what I know from prior exercises and prior proofs in the book:

1. $(g\circ f)$ is bijective
2. $(g \circ f)^{-1}$ is bijective
3. $((g \circ f)^{-1})^{-1}$ is bijective
4. $(g \circ f)^{-1}(g \circ f \ (x)) = x$
5. $(g \circ f)^{-1}(((g \circ f)^{-1})^{-1}\ (x))=x$

The proof is as follows:

From $4$ and $5$ we know that: $(g \circ f)^{-1}(g \circ f \ (x)) = (g \circ f)^{-1}(((g \circ f)^{-1})^{-1}\ (x))$

From $2$, we have the following statement: $\forall z \in Z$ if $(g \circ f)^{-1}(z)=(g \circ f)^{-1}(z')$, then $z=z'$.

From $1$ and $3$ we have: $(g \circ f \ (X))=Z$ and $(((g \circ f)^{-1})^{-1} \ (X))=Z$.

Because every $z^* \in Z$ can be represented by a particular $(g \circ f \ (x^*))$ and a particular $(((g \circ f)^{-1})^{-1} \ (x^*))$, I am going to rewrite my earlier statement as:

$\forall z \in Z$ if $(g \circ f)^{-1}(g \circ f \ (x))=(g \circ f)^{-1}(((g \circ f)^{-1})^{-1}\ (x))$, then $(g \circ f \ (x))=(((g \circ f)^{-1})^{-1}\ (x))$.

Now, the consequent of this statement is certainly part of what I want...however, I cannot figure out how (informally stated) $\forall z \in Z \implies \forall x \in X$. I am struggling with the logical step(s) to get to this concluding statement. It's certainly intuitive that this SHOULD BE the case, but I cannot for the life of me figure out the proper wording to get here.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: See [Universal Generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization): if a fact/property holds of an object $x$ wahtever, it holds of every object. See example Tao, page 328.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thanks for the suggestion (I could not find the example Tao provides that you reference...perhaps we have different editions?). However, I am a little confused. I think what you are telling me is that $\forall x (P(x) \to Q(x)) \to (\forall x P(x) \to \forall x Q(x))$. However, I don't believe this is the situation that I have. $\forall z$ and $\forall x$ are different because $z \in Z$ and $x \in X$. I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA i somehow need to invoke that there is a one-to-one correspondence between $z\in Z$ and $x \in X$ because of the bijective nature of the functions (...and therefore $\forall z \in Z \implies \forall x \in X$) but I cannot see what the right symbolic wording is.

Comment: I think I can show that these two statements are logically equivalent: $\forall z \in Z, \exists  !x \in X$ s.t. $g \circ f (x) = z \land ((g \circ f)^{-1})^{-1}(x)=z$ $\iff$ $\forall x \in X, g \circ f(x) = ((g \circ f)^{-1})^{-1}(x)$

Comment: In 4 and 5, the variable $x$ is universally quantified.

Comment: In the last "big formula" you have $\forall z$ but $z$ does not occur in the formula. What does it mean ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA i'm not quite sure I understand you question. $z$ occurs in the formula...specifically, in the "$ ...= z$" line. I'm basically applying the definition of surjective.

Comment: In formula "∀z∈Z  if (g∘f)−1(g∘f (x))=(g∘f)−1(((g∘f)−1)−1 (x)), then (g∘f (x))=(((g∘f)−1)−1 (x))" there is no $z$ to which the quantifier applies.

Comment: The "strategy" for this type of proof is : premise $\forall x (x \ge 0)$; instantiate it : $x_0 \ge 0$; apply some correct "transformation : $x_0 +1 \ge 1$. Then, **due to the fact that** $x_0$ **is a variable whatever**, apply Universal generalization to conclude with $\forall x (x+1 \ge 1)$.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I did not know what "big formula" you were talking about. $z=g(f(x))$ and $z=((g\circ f)^{-1})^{-1}$ so the reference was implicit.

Comment: I do not think that the formula is correct... You have the formula $(g∘f)^{−1}(g∘f (x))=(g∘f)^{−1}(((g∘f)^{−1})^{−1} (x))$ and try to parse it: we have a variable $x$ referring to an "object" whatever. $(g∘f (x))$ is another object and so is $(g∘f)^{−1}(g∘f (x))$.

Comment: You have proved that this object is equal to ... (RHS). Then you conclude that, being they equal, also the arguments of the two occurences of the function $(g∘f)^{−1}$ must be equal, i.e. $(g∘f )(x)=((g∘f)^{−1})^{−1} (x)$.

Comment: Now, due to the fact that $x$ is whatever, apply UG to conclude.